# How to find similarity between meta description of a URL and an article?

Tags: python, google-search, similarity

I have an article stored in .txt file, and i am fetching meta description of various articles from the web by giving some search queries to Google. I need to compare meta description and article. Which technique should i use to do this??

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried anything? If not, give it a quick google and edit your question if you get stuck on a particular piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the IN function to see if strings exits.

For example:

```
lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."

if "Dr.Evil" in lorem:
    print("Found it")
else:
    print("Didn't find it")
```